# SRS in GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile with projection WGS84, when I added it to GeoServer, the Native SRS is Unknown 
[image: Unknown SRS]

and for Declared SRS I wrote EPSG:4326. However, the shapefile became a mess if opened in Layer Preview

[image]

Then I changed Declared SRS to EPSG:2400 (Swedish RT90), the shapefile can be shown in Layer Preview.

[image]

What could be the problem?

And if I have Google Maps as tile map, how can I overlay this shapefile on it with OpenLayers element? What's the difference between e.g. OpenLayers.xxx and ol.xxx?

Comment: Seems that the proj file is lying to you, that is why geoserver allows you to override it.

Comment: @iantbut can I do something about it? I'm new to OpenLayer and GeoServer, so I have no idea what should I do to it. Besides, nither of them worked in new ol.layer.Image({ source: wmsSource }).

Comment: There is no need to do anything, just set 2400 and proceed as usual.